# IE 10 does not show background-image after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, form-submit

I have:

```
<div class="a" style="display:none">
    <div class="b" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 69px; height: 69px; background: url(../images/bg-loading.png) repeat-y;">
        .......
    </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
        $(".a").show();
        return true;
    });
});
```

`image-background` is not displayed on IE 10 and Chrome, but it works in FF. I tried to start without `display:none`, then to hide div, and then to show it on submit, and guess what - it works. I believe the possible reason - IE 10 'optimises' and does not load new images after submit has begun? How to fix it?

Again, if I touch div "b" through F12 (just select and deselect hidden element in debugger) or if I start without `display:none` - it works correctly. If I start hidden - it will not show background (but will show content).

Comment: Try preloading the image.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, I created visible `<img>` tag at the bottom of page and it shows my image perfectly. But `image-background` of my div still does not work. How can I preload it in another more helpful way?

Comment: Can you please show the full contents of that `style` attribute?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, have added to question.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you submitting a form on `document.ready` ?

If you *must* do this -- as opposed to using ajax, or - loading whatever you're loading in the first place, then replace `document` with your div --

```
$(".b").ready(function(){ [...] });
```

If it really is like you say - and the browsers refuse to load content after something has been submitted, then that should work --

Comment: Do not quite understand your message. I install submit handler when DOM is ready. What is wrong with that part of my code?

Comment: Well, why would you immediately submit a form when the page loads? You can always just `$.ajax` some data back to the server if that's what you need to do, but otherwise, the content should be loaded on the first set of requests..

Comment: I do not immediately submit a form -- I install submit event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I was not able to eliminate this issue in all major browsers. Have switched from `display: none` to `visibility: hidden` in my website architecture.